# Full height responsive table with contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have application where I'm using bootstrap. On this app one of my views contains table on left side and some data on right side. In order to have best user experience I stretch the table to full height so user can see as many rows as his device lets him. For the rest rows he can use scrollbar.

The problem is that if user has really small device then data on ride side goes out of container(gray area) which looks ugly. Is there any option to make my ride side not go outside gray area?

Please note that my container has to be dynamic 100% height to cover whole page. Im looking for solution that doesnt use javascripts.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-col col-1">
      <div class="my-table">
        <div class="my-table-wrapper">
          <div class="my-table-wrapper-2">
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-col col-2">
      <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2<br>2 of 2<br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/71230/)

(Works in chrome only, not sure why)

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Check this once I have chhanged the height of container class to auto instead of 100%. Hope this helps

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-table
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table-row
{
  display: table-row;
}

.my-col
{
  height: 100%;
}
.my-table-wrapper
{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.my-table-wrapper-2
{
  position: absolute;

}

.container
{
  height: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-row
{
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.col-1
{
  background-color: blue;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.col-2
{
  background-color: aqua;
}

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 my-col col-1">
  <div class="my-table">
  <div class="my-table-wrapper">
  <div class="my-table-wrapper-2">
  <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 my-col col-2">
      <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2<br>2 of 2<br>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/71287/

Comment: As I state previously I need solution that has full height.

Comment: Change the height of content as per you needed

Comment: With 100% height its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-table
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table-row
{
  display: table-row;
}

.my-col
{
  height: 100%;
}
.my-table-wrapper
{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}



.container
{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.my-row
{
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.col-1
{
  background-color: blue;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.col-2
{
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-col col-1">
      <div class="my-table">
        <div class="my-table-wrapper">
          <div class="my-table-wrapper-2">
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
            <div class="table-row">data</div>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 my-col col-2">
     
      <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2<br>2 of 2<br>
      <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2 <br>2 of 2<br>2 of 2<br>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Table must be on the left side and data must be on right side. Not 1 on top of another.